# Convert react build into react project again

Tags: reactjs, build

I just created a react build, deployed the build and deleted the complete project. Now when i need all the files of the project again, i am only having the react build.
Can we convert react build into project files again.?

Tried to recover the files but i am not able to recover it.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, no. building a React project involves compiling sources code into production ready minified code. Similar to `npm run eject` in Create React App, this cannot be reversed.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't, but there are few ways which may help a little bit.

**If you didn't set the "GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false", then try this way below**

1. Run the program and go to inspect tab in browser.
2. There go to source tab and there you can see the files tree, and click that to see the codes of each pages.

Mostly it will be there if you didn't set false for sourcemap.